# What is the prototypical unit testing framework for non oo languages?

Tags: unit-testing

Every language that supports Object Orientation has a port of xUnit. What about for non-oo languages? Are there advantages, or different ways of doing things, and if so, is there a prototypical example (like xUnit is for OO languages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wikipedia has a nice page listing the testing frameworks by language: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks